# Sympy no arguments in functions

Tags: sympy

I have some fairly long sympy expressions and I would like not to print the arguments of all these functions. I'm searching for a general solution because I have more than thirty functions in my equations.

Example:

```
a=sy.Function("a")
b=sy.Function("b")
expr=a(theta,phi)*b(zeta,theta)
sy.print_latex(expr,no_args=True)

a*b

sy.print_latex(expr)
a(theta,phi)*b(zeta,theta)
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: The simple way is just to replace the functions with symbols when printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom latex printer, and override the method responsible to create latex code of applied functions. Then, you need to inform `init_printing` that you want to use the newly created printer. Here is how:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter
from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef

class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    """ Extended Latex printer with a new option:

    applied_no_args : bool
        wheter applied undefined function should be
        rendered with their arguments. Default to False.
    """
    def __init__(self, settings=None):
        self._default_settings.update({
                "applied_no_args": False,
            }
        )
        super().__init__(settings)
        
    def _print_Function(self, expr, exp=None):
        if isinstance(expr, AppliedUndef) and self._settings["applied_no_args"]:
            if exp is None:
                return expr.func.__name__
            else:
                return r'%s^{%s}' % (expr.func.__name__, exp)
        return super()._print_Function(expr, exp)

def my_latex(expr, **settings):
    return MyLatexPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)

init_printing(latex_printer=my_latex, applied_no_args=True)
x, y, z = symbols("x:z")
f = Function("f")(x, y, z)
f
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was sure it was possible but I didn t have the knowledges to make it. :)

Comment: I tried to use your code just to try it out but it's not working. To show the function, I'm doing print(latex(f)). Thanks

Comment: Use `print(my_latex(f))`.

Comment: It's still not working but I found another solution, I just have to replace like that and it s working :
```
def my_latex_printer(expr_latex):
    expr_latex=expr_latex.replace(r"\left(\zeta,\theta,\phi \right)","")
    expr_latex=expr_latex.replace(r"\left(\zeta,\theta \right)","")
    expr_latex=expr_latex.replace(r"\left(\zeta,\mu \right)","")
    expr_latex=expr_latex.replace(r"\left(\theta,\phi \right)","")
    expr_latex=expr_latex.replace(r"\left(\theta,\phi \right)","")
    expr_latex=expr_latex.replace(r"\left(\zeta \right)","")
    return(expr_latex)
```

Comment: I don t know how to create a code block sorry

Comment: I forgot the keyword argument. This is what you have to execute: `print(my_latex(f, applied_no_args=True))`, where `my_latex` is the function I created in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all AppliedUndef objects with a symbol having the same name but do you want functions with the same arg to behave the same? If so then use numbered symbols to keep track of the different arguments.

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef
from sympy.abc import x,y
reps = {}
def newfunc(name):
    i=1
    while (f:=Symbol(name + str(i))) in reps.values():
        i+=1
    return f

f,g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
expr = f(x) + g(1, 2) + f(y)/f(x)
>>> expr.replace(
lambda x: isinstance(x, AppliedUndef), 
lambda x: reps.setdefault(x, newfunc(x.func.name)))
f1 + g1 + f2/f1
```

Comment: It's working well and it's quite smart but I think I prefer the version of Davide_sd, my issue if I m derivating this expr, it acts like there is no arguments in the function. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you might want to select his as the preferred answer.

Comment: Okay thanks, I didn't know it was working like that.